# For a web app with Implicit Flow of Oauth 2.0, is there a solution avoiding asking user sign in from time to time?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, google-oauth

As Implicit Flow can't issue refresh token, it seems that we have to ask the user sign in again and again.

But I rarely see single page web app that requires the above (unpleasant) user experience.

My question is how the webapp using Implicit Flow avoids asking user sign in again and again?

Answer (score 1):

The standard technique is to redirect on an iframe and send a prompt=none parameter. If there is a session cookie present, the authorization server will issue updated tokens. This enables a silent refresh without impacting the end user.

Steps 6 and 22 of my [messages write up](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/24/spa-and-api-final-http-messages/)  show what this looks like.